# Whether block scheduling is done by GPU?

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, gpu

Can we assign a block to a specific SM programmatically? Can we get runtime information(number of blocks or warps,a block's or  warp's execution time etc.) of SM?

Answer (score 3):

1. No.
2. No.

Nothing of this sort is exposed by the standard CUDA runtime and driver APIs.

Comment: What about assigning a block or grid(kernel) to a specific GPU if multi-GPU? What runtime information we can obtain about GPU?